# How do I create a new tag - "messiah"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There may be an inactive tag for this already. It showed up as having no questions, and when I tried to enter it, nothing happened. The explanation for creating new tags on the help page says one just has to enter the tag and it will be created... but that did not work.

I think this tag will be useful, as many questions deal with the nature of the messiah, his mission and how the concept of the messiah evolved in the biblical text etc. So it is distinct from "messianic prophecy" - a tag with many entries. It is also distinct from the "christology" tag, as that is a specifically Christian category that does not apply in many cases.

Can someone help me create a tag for "messiah" ?

Comment: "messiah" is a synonym of the [messianic-prophecy tag](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tags/messianic-prophecy/synonyms). Whether it should be distinguished, well you'd have to make a more detailed case for that.

Comment: It's rather simple. There are many passages in the bible that refer to the messiah but are not prophetic. For example, In Zech 4 there are two "anointed ones" who are historical figures. Cyrus of Persia is also a messiah.  Many understand Isaiah's 'prophecies' about the messiah as a declaration about a person already born, namely Hezekiah. To understand all OT  references to the messiah as prophetic is to impose a Christian theology on a Jewish text....

Comment: Besides that, Jesus is called messiah or Christ many times, and people wonder if John the baptist is the messiah. The disciples wonder why Elijah must come before the messiah.  Paul discusses the messiah's role countless time. These passages are not prophetic.

Comment: I really meant that you should put that in a post, with specific question examples showing how the tags should be distinguished. But in this case it would probably be fine to reverse the synonym direction? If "messiah" was the main tag, I don't think we'd need a distinct "messianic-prophecy" tag.

Comment: "To understand all OT references to the messiah as prophetic is to impose a Christian theology on a Jewish text..." This isn't remotely true. But also not importantly to this discussion...